# torch.cuda.is_available() False after a fresh installation of drivers and cuda

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, cuda, nvidia-geforce

I installed CUDA and NVIDIA driver using the following two commands.

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers install

$ sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

However, now cuda is not available from within torch. Do you know how I could fix it?

```
$ python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'1.6.0'
>>> torch.version.cuda
'10.1'
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
```

I am also not sure why after installing the drivers still nvidia-smi is not working:

```
$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.


$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ lspci  | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106M [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed after I did a reboot:

```
(base) mona@mona:~$ nvidia-smi
Thu Sep 24 13:04:12 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.06    Driver Version: 450.51.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   54C    P8     8W /  N/A |    428MiB /  7982MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1256      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                275MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2422      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              151MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
(base) mona@mona:~$ python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'1.6.0'
>>> torch.version.cuda
'10.1'
>>> torch.cuda.is_
torch.cuda.is_available(    torch.cuda.is_initialized(
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True
```